# run a function of the controller in the views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my `HomeController`, I defined:

```
static void send_data_to_log(ref DateTime last_time)
{
   // do something
 }
```

in my index of the controller, I defined:

```
DateTime last_time = DateTime.Now;
ViewBag.my_last_time = last_time;
send_data_to_log(ref last_time);
```

now I want to use this function and this variable(last_time) in my index.cshtml file.

I tried:

```
<input type="hidden" name="" id="my_last_time" value="@ViewBag.my_last_time" />
@send_data_to_log(ViewBag.my_last_time);
```

but I got error :/

I want that the viewbag.my_last_time and the last_time will be updated in the function.

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MVC` is meant for `separation of concerns` . That's very bad idea to have logic on view pages.You can send date to the controller and call the function in the controller.

You can serialize your date and then use `AJAX` , to sent it to the controller and call those functions in the controller.